# Where is the button or portal for uploading in the manage templates section?

Tags: cognito-forms, upload

I am attempting to upload a custom document (to take advantage of the new merge document capabilities). The instructions say "Upload your template" - however, I cannot locate any button or portal in the manage templates section that would allow me to do so.

Can you point me to the correct place?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upload your document by pressing the Upload button in your Manage Document Templates menu:

[image]

If you cannot see this button, for whatever reason, I would recommend submitting a support ticket: https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/

Comment: You have to press **Customize** and then download the original template or cancel the download. Then the **Upload** button appears.